# Blender and Itunes

Tags: itunes, blender

I am currently working on a project using Blender. However, when I go to to use 
itunes and listen to my music at the same time, both of them get messy to work with.

1. If itunes is running and i want to render, itunes skips and is not responsive while i render a test photo or a scene.
2. If i am rendering while itunes is playing a song, it takes ages to get a keyframe done.

Both programs are not happy and are slow when i try to use them at the same time, should i use a dedicated computer for blender and to render my projects on that computer?

Comment: I'd choose a different and more efficient media player (i.e.: VLC).

Answer (score 2):

You might consider limiting the resources blender can use for rendering.  It could be better than having them fight eachother.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15247/how-to-configure-blender-so-that-it-uses-only-50-of-total-cpu-when-rendering

the link is to some answers on how to control blender's resource usage.

Comment: Thanks! I followed the steps in side of the link that you provided, Bender only spikes my CPU utilization for a brief period of time then it settled down around 60%  and stays their for the duration of the render!